What is the quote about 13 rivers of aparsemon?
Can some share the quote where this came from: "the righteous will bathe in 13 rivers of aparsemon"? I've seen it paraphrased online a lot but I can't find it in the reference listed (Avodah Zarah 3:1).

https://www.sefaria.org/Taanit.25a.14

https://www.sefaria.org/Sulam_on_Zohar%2C_Introduction.109.4

It's aparsemon (אֲפַרְסְמוֹן) - pure balsam, persimmon is a fruit also known as lotus.

@shmosel that's a good answer to have the question closed!

And the concept is also referenced in the Akdamus poem on Shavuos ... for anyone awake then and able to understand what it's saying ...
